# Iphone: CustomCell, can't set data

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uilabel

I try to make a custom cell with a Uilabel and textfield

And i get this:

-> http://data.imagup.com/9/1119535256.png

But it's not given given my value ("Titre" & "Valeur" are generic):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InscriptionCustomCell";

InscriptionCustomCell *cell = (InscriptionCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InscriptionCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell =  (InscriptionCustomCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

if(indexPath.section ==0)
{
    [cell.titreCell setText:[model.listModuleInfoPerso objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contenuCell setPlaceholder:[model.listModuleInfoPerso objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}else {
    [cell.titreCell setText:[model.listModuleInfoSupp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contenuCell setPlaceholder:[model.listModuleInfoSupp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
return cell;
```

}

No error :S, an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Put an NSLog in the [model.listModuleInfoPerso objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] so you can see what is coming out...

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to hook up the label and the text field from Interface Builder to the properties in your InscriptionCustomCell subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Here it seems that you haven't set the delegate for UITextField. So, please set delegate now and then you can access the TextField entry.